# Telebot, после удаления последнего сообщения пропадают кнопки меню, почему?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

Telebot, после удаления последнего сообщения пропадают кнопки меню, почему?
Как избавится от этого?

Comment: Потому что кнопки привязаны к сообщению, избавиться разве что отправить другое сообщение

Comment: Не понимаю логику, у меня идет register_next_step_handler(), идет вопрос, после действие, и как тут быть

Comment: Вы можете код добавить к вопросу? Ничего не понятно